# Access model in controller-action?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli, controller-actions

I'm editing an object with a form and want to save the changed object from within the controller-action which is bound to the submit-button. I don't want to bind the values directly to the template.

Here's the `admin/edit.hbs`

```
<form>
    <label>Title
      <input name="title" type="text" {{ bind-attr value=title }} />
    </label>
    <label>Permalink
      <input name="permalink" type="text" {{ bind-attr value=permalink }} />
    </label>
    <label>Post
      {{textarea value=body cols="80" rows="12"}}
    </label>
  <button {{ action 'submitAction' }}>Submit</button>
</form>
```

This is the controller `admin/edit.hbs`
import Ember from 'ember';

```
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({    
  actions: {
      submitAction: function() {
        var newTitle = this.get('title');
        // how to access the model here?
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the model you want is currently the model of your `ObjectController`, you can do one of two things:

1. Get the model directly:

   ```
   submitAction: function() {
       var model = this.get('model');
   }
   ```
2. Pass it to the handler in the template:

   ```
   // admin/edit.hbs
   <button {{action 'submitAction' model}}>Submit</button>

   // admin/edit.js
   submitAction: function(model) {

   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In an `ObjectController`, the model is stored as… `model`. You can access it like this:

```
var model = this.get('model');
model.set('title', newTitle);
```

If you’re not using the features of `ObjectController` that automatically bind `get` and `set` calls to the object, you probably shouldn’t use `ObjectController`. The code as you have it listed will be setting the `title` of your model directly from the input field.